# How to access alfresco explorer from alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need alfresco share to search files since only alfresco share has the preview of office files and not the explorer. But I need explorer in order to create forum space.How can I access share from explorer or vice versa, so the user can search files in share and ask questions in forum space of explorer?

Comment: Give your users both URLs?

Comment: I can give but the user has to login seperaytely for share and explorer, can I bypass one login if user is logged in another

Comment: You'll need to setup some form of SSO, various options exist to pick between, see the Alfresco docs or wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the forum/discussion of Share instead of using the old User Interface?
Follow the [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/discussions-intro.html) to see if this works.

If you still want to use 2 user interfaces be my guest, but then the only fix is to setup SSO for the systems.